How to escape properly a text in alpinejs/Laravel?
I am using alpinejs and laravel, I stored in the database this text: F & M, this part of my blade file:
.....
<input   type="text" name="title"   id="title"  x-model="title" required />
 ....

<script> 
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
      Alpine.data('MyForm', () => ({ 
              title: '{{ $post->title }}',
      })) 
 }) 
    </script> 

In the input text the title is displayed like this:
F &amp; M

I want it to be displayed like this: F & M . I don't want to use {!! !!} because it may be unsafe for my website, What can I do?

Can't you use the built-in decodeUriComponent() method? See the docs

Try this :
<script> 
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('MyForm', () => ({ 
        title: @json($post->title),
    })) 
 }) 
</script> 


It works!, thanks

Instead of directly providing the solution, explaining why the code works would be helpful. This approach allows others on the platform to understand both the problem and the solution better.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
